# C# : How to find if two string arrays contains same values

Tags: c#, string, split, dataset

I have two comma separated strings. 
A = "M,D,V" and B = "V,M"

I have to split(',') this string and compare the sub strings.

then I have to execute statement only if sub-strings present in A and B are equal and same.

Please help me write a login in an optimum way.

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with `System.Data.DataSet` which is what I'd expect given the title and tags. Are you *actually* just dealing with strings? Given that you know how to split, it sounds like you're really just talking about arrays, and the splitting part is irrelevant. Is that the case? Are you just asking about checking whether two arrays are equal in some respect? If so: a) is order important? b) is repetition important, e.g. is `{ "a", "a", "a" }` meant to compare equal to `{ "a" }`?

Comment: @unicorn2 productType.Split(',').Intersect(value.Split(','), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Any()  but as you can undestand, this only returns common elements.

Comment: "Please help me write a login in an optimum way. " Please provide at least you (first-attempted) non-optimum way

Comment: @S7H, Your question is not providing the required information to help you. Rewrite your question and provide more information, may be a sample code and describe what you are going to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

1. Lets assume that the order is important and repetition is also important.

E.g.

```
 // clearly not the same = false
  var A = "M,D,V";
  var B = "V,M";
// repetition = false
  var A = "M,V";
  var B = "M,V,V";
// same elements but different order = false
  var A = "M,V";
  var B = "V,M";
```

Then you can use

```
var answer = A.Split(',').SequenceEqual(B.Split(','));
```

2. If you want to ignore repetition you can add the Distinct method.

`var answer = A.Split(',').Distinct().SequenceEqual(B.Split(',').Distinct());`

In which case the results would be:

```
 // clearly not the same = false
  var A = "M,D,V";
  var B = "V,M";
// repetition = true
  var A = "M,V";
  var B = "M,V,V";
// same elements but different order = false
  var A = "M,V";
  var B = "V,M";
```

Answer (score 0):

The below function compares even the two strings are in different order only when those are equal in length.
**Note:** A string can't be equal if they are different in length.

```
    public static String compare(String str1, String str2)
    {
        String[] strArr1 = str1.Split(',');
        String[] strArr2 = str2.Split(',');
        int itr = 0;
        while (strArr1.Length == strArr2.Length && strArr2.Contains(strArr1[itr]))
        {
            itr++;
            if (itr == strArr1.Length)
            {
                return "The Strings contains same values.";
            }
        }
        return "The Strings does not contain same values.";
    }
```